# JavaScript: Form is not operating correctly after AJAX returns

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, dom

I have a list of buttons defined at the top of my JS `let deletePostBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button[name="delete_post"]');`. I am using `let` because I think it needs to be re-defined later.

When clicked, this button calls `e.preventDefault()` and uses custom `AJAX` that I've written (with the help of those here).

Load up the page, click the `DELETE` button, and everything works,  the element is removed and the elements are reloaded according to the database query the `AJAX` returns.

Now here is the problem. After the `AJAX` returns the data, and the elements are loaded, the next button clicked acts like a normal form and is no longer calling my `addEventListener`. I need it to call that `addEventListener` and have it run the `AJAX` all over again.

### IMPORTANT NOTE

Now if you look over the script, you'll notice that I make two `console.log()`s inside of my `get()` Promise. Which is nested inside of my `deletePostPromise()` Promise. These two `console.log()`'s output the expected data. Say I have five buttons, when clicked it initially returns `NodeList(5) [array of buttons]` and then it will return `NodeList(4) [array of buttons]`.

My guess is that my `let deletePostBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button[name="delete_post"]');` needs to be redefined later in the script, but I am not sure where.

### JavaScript

```
let deletePostBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button[name="delete_post"]');

// GET REQUEST TO RETRIEVE EVERY POST
const get = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open('GET', url, true);

    xhttp.onload = () => {
      if (xhttp.status == 200) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(xhttp.response));
      } else {
        reject(xhttp.statusText);
      }
    };

    xhttp.onerror = () => {
      reject(xhttp.statusText);
    };

    xhttp.send();
  });
}

// DELETE SPECIFIC POST
const deletePostPromise = (url, postID) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);

    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log('if (xhr.status == 200)');
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject(xhr.statusText);
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = () => {
      reject(xhr.statusText);
    };

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(postID);
  });
}

// MAKING THE CALL TO DELETE THE POST
if (deletePostBtn) {
  for (let i = 0; i < deletePostBtn.length; i++) {
    deletePostBtn[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(deletePostBtn); // Returns 'NodeList(5) [array]'

      const displayPostWrapper = document.querySelector('.col-8.pt-4');
      const displayPostSection = document.querySelectorAll('.col-8.pt-4 .row');
      const postID = document.querySelectorAll('#delete-post-id');

      deletePostPromise('http://localhost/mouthblog/ajax/delete_post.ajax.php', `id=${postID[i].value}`)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('JUST DELETED POST');
        })
        .then(() => {
          get('http://localhost/mouthblog/api/blog.php')
            .then(data => {
              console.log(data);

              displayPostWrapper.innerHTML = '';

              data.map(x => {
                displayPostWrapper.innerHTML += `<div class="row">
                                                   <article class="col-10 offset-1">
                                                     <h2 class="h2">${x.user_name}</h2>
                                                     <small>${x.date_created}</small>
                                                     &nbsp;
                                                     &nbsp;
                                                     <form class="" method="POST">
                                                       <button class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_post" type="submit">DELETE</button>
                                                       <input id="delete-post-id" name="post_id" type="hidden" value="${x.id}">
                                                     </form>
                                                     <hr>
                                                     <p class="lead">${x.content}</p>
                                                   </article>
                                                </div>
                                                `;
              }); // map

              let deletePostBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button[name="delete_post"]');
              console.log(deletePostBtn); // Returns 'NodeList(4) [array]
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: A suggestion - rather than redrawing all the posts that didn't get deleted when you delete something, can you just remove the one that did?  Your problem is likely due to not having event handlers set on the redrawn post delete buttons, so to fix either 1) don't redraw the posts or 2) add event handlers to all your new delete buttons once you redraw.

Comment: @James How do you suggest I add an event handler to each button, given they are dynamically created. Add an `onclick=` to the buttons themselves to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a different way to go about this, and I am going to post it here as the answer. It **could** help somebody.

### Suggest by @James in the OP comments

> A suggestion - rather than redrawing all the posts that didn't get
>   deleted when you delete something, can you just remove the one that
>   did? Your problem is likely due to not having event handlers set on
>   the redrawn post delete buttons, so to fix either 1) don't redraw the
>   posts or 2) add event handlers to all your new delete buttons once you
>   redraw.

Thinking about the future of this web app, I went the route of just removing the element from the `DOM` completely. Using a built-in JavaScript method - `.remove()` not only deletes it from the DOM, but the user does not have to wait for the `AJAX` to return the data from the database. Also, the code is a lot cleaner, developer friendly, and just easier on the eyes.

By removing unnecessary `AJAX` calls, I've not only sped up the app, but removed **`56`** lines of code.

### JS

```
const deletePostBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button[name="delete_post"]');
const displayPostWrapper = document.querySelector('.col-8.pt-4');
const displayPostSection = document.querySelectorAll('.col-8.pt-4 .row');
const postID = document.querySelectorAll('#delete-post-id');

// DELETE SPECIFIC POST
const deletePostPromise = (url, postID) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);

    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log('if (xhr.status == 200)');
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject(xhr.statusText);
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = () => {
      reject(xhr.statusText);
    };

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(postID);
  });
}

// MAKING THE CALL TO DELETE THE POST
if (deletePostBtn) {
  for (let i = 0; i < deletePostBtn.length; i++) {
    deletePostBtn[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(deletePostBtn);

      displayPostSection[i].remove();

      deletePostPromise('http://localhost/mouthblog/ajax/delete_post.ajax.php', `id=${postID[i].value}`);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the event listener to your elements again at the ajax response handler. Because you deleted those elements that had an event listener attached.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do I need to write another .addEventListener for the newly generated buttons? Where exactly? Do i need to redefine the buttons array?

Comment: At the resolve method it seems `resolve(JSON.parse(xhttp.response));`

Answer (score 0):

If you use event delegation to handle delete button clicks you only have to set up one listener, and you can add as many new delete buttons as you like, and they will all work.

I've moved the main guts of your delete button handler into its own function (doStuff).  I moved the declaration of displayPostWrapper outside the handler so that we can capture click events on it, check if the click occurred on a delete button, and if so call doStuff.

I took care of a problem that you had where your post_id was being set by an element with duplicated ID - I got rid of that ID altogether and it now uses a querySelector to find the correct element.

```
const displayPostWrapper = document.querySelector('.col-8.pt-4');

displayPostWrapper.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  // the parent was clicked - lets see if the click was actually on a delete button
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON" && e.target.name == "delete_post") {
    doStuff.call(e.target, e);
  }
});

function doStuff(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(deletePostBtn); // Returns 'NodeList(5) [array]'

  const displayPostSection = document.querySelectorAll('.col-8.pt-4 .row');
  const postID = this.form.querySelector('input[name=post_id]').value;

  deletePostPromise('http://localhost/mouthblog/ajax/delete_post.ajax.php', `id=${postID}`)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('JUST DELETED POST');
    })
    .then(() => {
      get('http://localhost/mouthblog/api/blog.php')
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);

          displayPostWrapper.innerHTML = '';

          data.map(x => {
            displayPostWrapper.innerHTML += `<div class="row">
                                               <article class="col-10 offset-1">
                                                 <h2 class="h2">${x.user_name}</h2>
                                                 <small>${x.date_created}</small>
                                                 &nbsp;
                                                 &nbsp;
                                                 <form class="" method="POST">
                                                   <button class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_post" type="submit">DELETE</button>
                                                   <input name="post_id" type="hidden" value="${x.id}">
                                                 </form>
                                                 <hr>
                                                 <p class="lead">${x.content}</p>
                                               </article>
                                            </div>
                                            `;
          }); // map

          let deletePostBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button[name="delete_post"]');
          console.log(deletePostBtn); // Returns 'NodeList(4) [array]
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hmm... While I appreciate the response, with what you have written it is now ALWAYS submitting as a normal form. I think the `doStuff()` function is being completely ignored.

Comment: Oops, I forgot that the .nodename property always returns the name in UPPER CASE.  Fixed - give it another go!

Comment: Thanks but I've gone a different route. If you'd still like to help you can take a look over here for my newest question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468289/javascript-prepend-element-to-dom-and-inherit-event-handler . Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: Hey, I'm glad you decided to delete the element from the DOM and be done with it, it's a much cleaner solution.